# Multiple request from a web server

Tags: web-applications, request

First of all I think this is a common problem, but cannot find a really good solution;

We have a web application, some of its request takes more than a minute. In the mean time we should be able to do more job with that application (for instance a simple lookup from database) but web server does not respond to any request until the previous one finishes.

As we are starting to develop this application from scratch we can embed everything including the option to change the web server also. Which web server or which methodology do you think we should follow ?

By the way we will use PHP for this.

Thank you very much,
Baris

Comment: This seems more like an application design question which would be better suited to [so] or http://programmers.stackexchange.com rather that SF.

Comment: It is more like a combination of both actually. Because maybe there is a solution transparent to programming language and we dont know, right ?

Comment: There's something desperately wrong with your setup __and__ the application, and this question in it's current form is not likely to be answered anywhere on SE. If it's a _must_ to ask here, I'd start with splitting it into two: 1) Why it takes one minute (!) per request. 2) Why our server blocks until the request is processed. (1) May be ok for SF, (2) is probably better on SO. And provide 10 times more information than you did so far.

Comment: @Sandman4 You are most probably right about 2 but not about 1 because that specific request requires 3rd party application to respond. For 2; you may be right, we may be missing something but why I didnt give much information is I am looking for a solution without affecting your ideas. Also I am looking for an answer like; "You should use nginx because it lets you to open N threads at the same time" or maybe; "Use apache and enable module X to do this".

Comment: Oops - i should be vice versa (1) for SO, (2) for SF, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Apache because it lets you to open N threads at the same time.

(Or use Nginx because it serves multiple concurrent requests from it's single thread.)

Comment: haha, v. good :) While they're at it they should think about re-writing it in Lua